# Is there any .NET binding for GObject Introspection?

Tags: c#, .net, gnome, gobject, gobject-introspection

I googled it and in the official [page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection), it said that they have .NET binding. But when I had a look on the [list](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GObjectIntrospection/Users?action=show&redirect=GObjectIntrospection%2FUsers) of bindings it provides, I couldn't find any binding for C#. So I wonder if such kind of binding really exist now.

Answer (score 1):

i not use c# but you have already followed these links?

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/gapi/

Comment: I use C# because I'm developing an ASP.NET application in my project and I have done half of it. Now I need to use [GStreamer Editing Services](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-editing-services/html/) in the backend to finish the left half part. As it uses GObject, I'm looking for .net bindings to let me use it in my ASP.NET application.